# Sqlite with phonegap (don't persist structure of DB)

Tags: sqlite, cordova

i try to use sqlite with phonegap on icenium and i have to ask a question (maybe a noob question).
In fact i cant persist my datas structure in sqlite.
I explain, i created two functions on onDeviceReady(),
one is createDB() other is createTables(), and if i erase the createTables() function, my structure erases.

Thanks you in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: can you please specify your question...what you want to do??

Comment: Hi, I want to create a local database in my app. But i can't "fix" my structure and datas in sqlite DB. In fact i need to initialize the structure's DB for each load of phonegap... Is it normal?

Comment: Hi...whenever your html page change at that time you must be initialize database on new page on Pageinit method..yes its normal

Comment: There are some phonegap plugins for SQLite, have you tried to use them? They create a SQLite DB on the internal directory of your application.

Comment: Ok can you tell me which plugin can i use ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello See this example ....how its working SQlite with HTML5

http://www.tegdesign.com/offline-html5-web-database-techniques-using-html5sql-js/

Comment: Hi, thanks you for reply but i have the same problem.I work with icenium, and I think the database is not built physically, because when I run my application structure is re-created.